# Script engine for C# application

Tags: c#, .net

I need to include in an application I am developing, a feature to allow easy customization of a module. In fact it will be nice to use some kind of scripting to modify the behaviour of a calculation process that the application provides. I am developing the application in C# and Roslyn... but how can I pass a context (parameters and values) to a Roslyn script and receive a response back?

Comment: Allowing end users to provide scripts at the language level creates a huge vulnerability. Users would not only modify the behaviour of your calculations but also create any other code that will run side-by-side with your app code, with full priviledges to connect to your databases etc. Rather than a fully fledged parser of a complete language, you rather waht a domain language for math expressions, something like http://mathparser.org/.

Answer (score 2):

If C# is appropriate language for your case Roslyn is a good choice.
Take a look at [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting)  NuGet package. It allows to execute pieces of C# code stored in plain strings.
For example:
`await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("Console.WriteLine(\"Hello world!\")");`